# Commits show in github, but dont in local repository

Tags: git, github

When I try to clone any repository in github, the clone copies only the last commit.
I type git reflog and just show the last commit, but if I type git log all the committees are displayed. Type git pull and it displays the message "Already up do date".
Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: which problem? I don't see any

Comment: What do you mean? I would like to have all commits in the local repository, not just the last one.

Comment: git log, you see all

Comment: yes but I can not access with git checkout the previous commits even though they are listed with git log

Answer (score 3):

1. `git-reflog` displays only updates to references in your local branch- so you shouldn't expect to see any commits but the `HEAD` show up after cloning. The ([official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)) explains a little more about how `reflog` functions differently than `git log`.
2. The `@` operator functions on the nth **branch** not the nth **commit**. As you pulled only the master branch, this command fails properly.  Instead you should use `git checkout HEAD~3` to get the 3rd previous commit.  As an alternative, you can do `git checkout <commit>` and simply find the commit hash in the GitHub UI.

Comment: i type git checkout HEAD @ {3} for example, but the message "fatal: Log for 'HEAD' only has 1 entries." But in the repository in github there is more than one commit